How do I get descriptor for JavaScript class constructor function?
Is it possible for me to get the descriptor for the actual constructor method of a JS class?  I am writing my own little wrapper around Express to try and procedurally generate routes and stuff (and I am sure there are plenty of other libraries to do this, but it's a learning experience).
If I iterate through the function descriptors for a class prototype, I can convert the 'value' property to a string that represents a single method.  If I call getString() on the descriptor for 'constructor' I get the entire class.  I ONLY want the body of the constructor.  I could add more parsing logic, but there has to be a way to do this.
Here is a simple controller:
const
    BaseController = require('../src/baseController');

/**
 * Handle requests for the home page
 */
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    /**
     * @param settings Controller settings
     * @param vault Injected vault client
     */
    constructor(settings, vault) {
        super(settings);
        this.vault = vault;
    }

    /**
     * Serve the landing page
     * @returns 
     */
    async get() {
        await this.renderAsync({ pageTitle: 'Pechanga Demo' });
    }
}

module.exports = HomeController;

Here is what currently comes back for 'get':
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(controllerType.prototype, 'get').value.toString()

async get() {
   await this.renderAsync('index', { pageTitle: 'Pechanga Demo' });
}

However, getting the descriptor for 'constructor' returns the entire class body:
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(controllerType.prototype, 'constructor').value.toString()

I really want is just:
    constructor(settings, vault) {
        super(settings);
        this.vault = vault;
    }

Is this possible without parsing the entire class body?

Please reduce this code to [mcve] form, and please also run it through some code formatting, because it's kind of all over the place at the moment (literally).

Hopefully that's a little better.

"a string that represents a single method" - what do you want to do with that? You shouldn't need this in the first place. If you're going to parse method definitions, you may as well parse the whole class definition - you need the same JS parser for both anyway.

I don't need the entire definition of the method, I only need the parameter list (names, order, and default values).  This is used to create an argument list/array from values in a dictionary.

@KrisOye Parsing arbitrary default values means you have to parse arbitrary javascript expressions. So just use a JS parser already.

I guess the real question is: what problem are you facing where being able to do this would solve that problem? Because this feels very close to an XY problem. What's your actual use-case here, with a concrete example of something you can't do right now without knowing the declare-time argument list? Because if you just need to wrap express functions, using the spread operator so you don't even need to care about what the arguments are would probably make more sense than this?

This sounds like XY problem indeed. Consider reasking with the explanation what you want to achieve, the answer would be different from what you try. This wouldn't be possible in a reasonable way with vanilla JS. There's no separate constructor function per se in JS, as the answer explains. If you want to have DI with constructor params being processed, TS is your best bet. This is how Angular DI (available separately as injection-js) works. This info is lost at JS runtime, you can learn from how it handled DI in JS, there had to be separate field, static inject = ['settings', 'vault']

The issue here is that Javascript does not have the concept of classes, nor constructors. Yes, it might have a class and a constructor keyword in recent versions, but under the hood, it is still a prototype based langauge. Those keywords are just syntactic sugar - and that is what's causing the problem, because it makes you assume that .prototype.constructor had something to do with thwe constructor() syntax in classes. However, this is not the case.
Let's take a look at this minimal example:
class Bar {
    constructur (value) {
        this.property1 = value;
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar {
    constructor (value1, value2) {
        super(value1);
        this.property2 = value2;
    }
}

In traditional plain Javascript, you'd set this up like this:
function Bar (value) {
    this.property1=value;
}

function Foo (value1, value2) {
    Bar.call(this,value1);
    this.property2 = value2;
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype, Bar.prototype);

which in turn is syntactic sugar for
var Bar = function Bar (value) {
    this.property1=value;
}
var Foo = function Foo (value1, value2) {
    Bar.call(this,value1);
    this.property2 = value2;
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype, Bar.prototype);

Now, if we look at Foo, it's obviously a function - and we can clearly see that it is one  as we assign one to the variable explicitely. As all functions, the toString() method of it will return it's source code (unless it's native).
Again as all functions in Javascript, Foo has a property called .prototype which only exists to set up the proper [[Prototype]] for objects created with new Foo. This object then has a property called constructor which points at the function it was created for - which is Foo itself.
So Foo.prototype.constructor.toString() is the same as Foo.toString() and will print the source code of Foo - just as you'd expect.
You see clearly here: the .constructor property of a function's .prototype Property does not have any relation to the constructor() syntax in classes. It exists completely independently.
Now, if you use the syntactic sugar that makes you think Javascript had classes, the toString() method of Foo.prototype.constructor will behave exactly as before: it will print the source code that defined Foo.
Which is, in the "we used syntactic sugar"-case, class Foo extends Bar {constructor (value1, value2) {super(value1); this.property2 = value2;}}.
So, what you are seeing is "working as expected".
If you want the contents of constructor() alone, you need to either set it up the traditional way and not use the class-notation, or you need to parse the source code of your class and extract the relevant part. There is no function that will do this for you, and there is no object that corresponds to the contents of constructor(), as it does not actually exist within the compiled code.

Not related to this issue, I would like to add that I, personally, prefer to write the most verbose and plain JS code for anything. This might sound inconvenient, especially as there is a lot of syntactic sugar that allows us to write shorter code - but it's also hiding basic concepts of JS so we don't understand anymore what's actually happening.

I know classes are sugar and I have created entire "object-oriented" APIs using vanilla JS like @johannes-h but I like syntactic sugar :) ... which is the goal of my exercise here.  I want more sugar without having to resort to doing any transpiling, etc.

So, to summarize, the answer to my actual question is a resounding "no".

@KrisOye Sadly, yes. Unless parsing the string is an option.
